# Quitting my gas station job. Need advice

Tags: resignation

As I mentioned in the title, I work at a gas station and plan on quitting. My problem is that my actual bosses are rarely at the station (they own 8 stations) and my manager only works on days that I will be in class (high school).

I might be able to go on Tuesday morning and give it then. Is this the best course of action? Should I call them instead?

Edit: I am giving 2 weeks notice, I am just unsure of how to best deliver it.

Comment: Which gas station do you work for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally when you leave a job, you give some notice - often two weeks or so.  That allows your bosses to figure out what to do schedule-wise and gives them time to adjust schedules and/or hire a replacement.

If you're planning to quit without giving notice, be aware that will make it unlikely your bosses give you a positive recommendation in the future.  As a high school student, a poor (or missing) recommendation may make it difficult to get future employment, particularly summer employment while you are in school.

If you are planning to give notice, you can do so over the phone.  I would do so immediately.  If you are not planning to give notice, I would highly recommend doing so in person; that way, you can explain why you are unable to give notice (for example, if school is causing too much difficulty), and give them a chance to give you a way out that doesn't hurt your recommendation and future job prospects.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am giving 2 weeks. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score -4):

Take care of YOU.

"Giving notice" is a old-fashioned custom from the days when companies were supposed to offer the same courtesy to their employees if there was a pending layoff.  Nowadays, we have at-will employment where a business can lay you off at any time, without reason, but people who haven't caught up with the times are still following the old way as if it still matters.

There is no legal requirement to give notice.  Anything in the neighborhood of a "bad recommendation" as a result of you ending your employment -- with notice, or not -- may constitute grounds for you to sue your former employer  for [defamation](http://employment.findlaw.com/hiring-process/is-a-former-employer-s-bad-reference-illegal-.html).  (I am not an attorney).

If you are concerned about message delivery, you can (a) send a certified letter - they'll get it, and you can prove that it was received; or (b) send a registered e-mail through a service like [RPost.com](http://www.rpost.com/).  In both cases, absolutely no one can say you didn't give proper notice -- if that's still a concern -- because both services offer proof of delivery.